# CG-modules: what does this notation mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, representation-theory

I am trying to solve a question, but I do not know what the notation used means. If anyone could help me out that'd be great! I don't need help doing the proof, just what the notation means would be brilliant.

I have a finite group $G$ and $V, W$ finite-dimensional  $\mathbb{C}G$-modules. Let $L:V\rightarrow W$ be a linear map and define $p:V\rightarrow W$ by $p(x)=\sum_{g\in G}g^{-1}Lg(x)$.

Prove that $p$ is a homomorphism of $\mathbb{C}G$-modules.

I don't understand the what the definition of $p$ means.

Thanks,

Andy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $g\in G$ and $x\in V$, $g^{-1}Lg(x)$ is the element of $W$ obtained by first multiplying $x$ by $g$ using the $\mathbb{C}G$-module structure of $V$, then applying the linear map $L$ to get an element of $W$, and then multiplying that element of $W$ by $g^{-1}$ using the $\mathbb{C}G$-module structure of $W$.  Then $p(x)$ is just the sum of the elements of $W$ you obtain in this way using each element $g\in G$.

Comment: Thank you Eric. I have managed to prove that p is a linear map also, but have hit a bit of a stumbling block on the second condition for a CG-homomorphism. When trying p(hx). (For some h in G) I get the following (omitting the sum sign) g^-1 Lg(hx). Which can be written as g^-1 L (gh)x. But I can't seem to get any further than that. Any ideas? Thanks, Andy.

Comment: The key thing you want to use is that the set $\{gx:g\in G\}$ is equal to the set $\{ghx:g\in G\}$, since $\{gh:g\in G\}=G$.

Comment: Thanks again Eric, that makes sense - I think I was just overthinking it. I'm trying some questions from my uni days and I'm not quite as switched on as I used to be!

Answer (score 1):

The notation here is a little awkward, so I'm going to adjust it a bit. You have that $V$ is a $\mathbb{C}G$-module, so for each $v\in V$ and $g\in G$, you should know what $g.v$ means (and similarly for $g.w$, $w\in W$).

Now,  starting from a linear transformation $L:V\to W$ and $x\in V$ we can compute $g^{-1}.L(g.x)$ (that is, act on $x$ with $g$, map it over to $W$ using $L$, and then act on that by $g^{-1}$). This produces a vector in $W$.

We can do this for each $g\in G$, and since $W$ is a vector space, it makes sense to add all these elements together. In the end, we get a map
$$p(x)=\sum_{g\in G} g^{-1}.L(g.x).$$
It is claimed that this is a $G$-map, so you need to prove that $p(h.x)=h.p(x)$ for every $h\in G$.

---

*Remark about notation:* Saying that $V$ and $W$ are $\mathbb{C}G$-modules is the same as having homomorphisms
$$\pi_V:\mathbb{C}G\to \mathrm{End}(V)\;\;\mbox{ and }\;\;\pi_W:\mathbb{C}G\to \mathrm{End}(W)$$ 
Therefore, $\pi_V(g):V\to V$ is a linear map, as is $\pi_W(g):W\to W$. If we abuse notation and identify $g$ with its image under these maps, then we can interpret $g^{-1}Lg(x)$ as the composition of maps
$$
V\longrightarrow^{\pi_V(g)}V\longrightarrow^LW\longrightarrow^{\pi_W(g^{-1})}W
$$